# Scala - sbt, main.scala and custom package

Tags: scala, package, sbt, customization

I use SBT 0.11.0. It requires that all sources must be placed in:

```
[project]/src/main/scala/
```

However I want a custom package such as:

```
[project]/src/com/test/...
```

I can leave things as SBT requires, then specify in every source file the custom package:

```
package com.test
```

But I got some problems with Eclipse auto-features such as import statements, generating new classes... Eclipse always adds `main.scala` before `com.test`. Is there something I can do to solve this?

**Edited**

For example I have this:

```
[project]
  src
    main
      scala
        com
          test
            A.scala
              package com.test
              ...
            B.scala
              package com.test
              ...
```

In `B`, I use some functions of `A`, I type it, then press `Ctrl+Shift+O` to let Eclipse import `A`. Eclipse does this:

```
import main.scala.com.test.A
```

But in `A` I set package to `com.test` (not `main.scala.com.test`).

This is small example. But when I have many source files, I need to refactor my code, things will be harder...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are confusing source folders and packages!

sbt by convention uses the source folder *src/main/scala* for Scala code. Within this folder you can create whichever packages you want, e.g. a subfolder *foo/bar* with a file *Baz.scala* that contains the following code:

```
package foo.bar

object Baz {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand what you meant. I think my question is not clear. Let me edit it.

Comment: Heiko is right. Make sure in your Eclipse project properties that you have `src/main/scala` as your source folder (not just `src`).

Comment: Thanks Heiko too, I was confusing  :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you use the [eclipse plugin for sbt](https://github.com/typesafehub/sbteclipse) then you can tell sbt to generate an Eclipse project which has all the details configured to work correctly with sbt's project structure.  All the details you need to add it to your sbt project and to run it are at the link above.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried sbteclipse, it works fine. But currently I don't need it. If I need such the plugin, I will know how to find it. Thank you again :-)